# which fuse version in my kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, package, version, fuse

I want to know which fuse version do I have, when attempting to execute:

```
locate -i -r /fuse
```

I get:

```
/lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/kernel/fs/fuse
/lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/kernel/fs/fuse/cuse.ko
/lib/modules/3.0.0-32-generic/kernel/fs/fuse
/lib/modules/3.0.0-32-generic/kernel/fs/fuse/cuse.ko
/usr/include/fuse
/usr/include/fuse.h
/usr/include/fuse/cuse_lowlevel.h
/usr/include/fuse/fuse.h
/usr/include/fuse/fuse_common.h
/usr/include/fuse/fuse_common_compat.h
/usr/include/fuse/fuse_compat.h
/usr/include/fuse/fuse_lowlevel.h
/usr/include/fuse/fuse_lowlevel_compat.h
/usr/include/fuse/fuse_opt.h
/usr/include/linux/fuse.h
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/fuse.pc
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/fuse-emulator-gtk:fuse-gtk.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/fuse-emulator-sdl:fuse-sdl.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/fuse.png
/usr/share/doc/fuse-utils
/usr/share/doc/libfuse-dev/examples/fusexmp.c
/usr/share/doc/libfuse-dev/examples/fusexmp_fh.c
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse_utils
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/fuse-utils
/usr/share/man/man1/fuser.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/fusermount.1.gz
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12/fs/fuse
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12/fs/fuse/Kconfig
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12/fs/fuse/Makefile
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12/include/linux/fuse.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic/include/config/fuse
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic/include/config/aufs/br/fuse.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic/include/config/fuse/fs.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic/include/linux/fuse.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-32/fs/fuse
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-32/fs/fuse/Kconfig
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-32/fs/fuse/Makefile
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-32/include/linux/fuse.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-32-generic/include/config/fuse
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-32-generic/include/config/aufs/br/fuse.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-32-generic/include/config/fuse/fs.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-32-generic/include/linux/fuse.h
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse-utils.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse-utils.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse-utils.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse-utils.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse-utils.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse-utils.preinst
```

Any idea where the information I need is located ?

Comment: While his answer is now accepted, it is unfortunately weong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the version of the fusermount utility like this:

```
fusermount -V
```

Comment: This lists the version of the fusermount command, it has no relationshp to the fuse version in the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `fusermount -V`, [as presented by @jdlourenco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32810689/4561887), you can also run `sshfs -V`. It shows the `fusermount -V` output as the last line.

Example runs and output on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine:

```bash
$ fusermount -V
fusermount3 version: 3.9.0
```

and:

```bash
$ sshfs -V
SSHFS version 3.7.1
FUSE library version 3.9.0
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.31
fusermount3 version: 3.9.0
```

### Other References:

1. My answer here: [Ask Ubuntu: How to prevent SSHFS mount freeze after changing connection after suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/a/942820/327339)

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer should be jdlourenco's one.
Boh's anwser isn't bad, but not clear enough for newbies and the shell line is too specific (in my case, Ubuntu 16.04, no results)

On Debian / Ubuntu, check using dpkg
`dpkg --get-selections | grep fuse`